# Как посмотреть действия определенного пользователя на сайте?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Когда заходил, выходил, писал/удалял/редактировал комментарий и т.д. Как это реализовать? Буду рад даже ссылке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все зависит от того на чем построен ваш сайт. Общий ответ в момент добавления/удаления/обновления записывайте информацию.